# How can I debug a windows x64 executable compiled by FASM in Windbg?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, symbols, fasm

As FASM does not export .pdb symbol file only .fas file, is there a workaround? 
I know there is some program like fas2pdb or pecvt, however all of them work on 86 only.

Comment: Try use the listing file. Manually. Put it next to the disassembly in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=118458
It's addon for IDA which adds debug symbols from FAS file, haven't tested but it should work.